# How add extra vertical spacing between dotteds using text-decoration-style: dotted;

Tags: html, css

There's a way to add some extra vertical spacing between dots using `text-decoration-style: dotted`;?

I have this anchor:

```css
.anchor {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
  text-underline-offset: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="anchor" href="">
  Hi! Click me
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. You would have to use a pseudo-element with a radial gradient.

```css
:root {
  --gap: 4px;
  --color: red;
  --distance: -5px;
}

.anchor {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2em;
}

.anchor:after {
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: var(--distance);
  left: 0;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, var(--color) 1px, transparent 1.5px);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: var(--gap) 4px;
}

.v2 {
  --gap: 12px;
  --color: green;
  --distance: -10px;
}
```

```html
<a class="anchor" href="">
  Hi! Click me
</a>

<a class="anchor v2" href="">
  Hi! Click me My gap is wider
</a>
```